# How to create multiple files with different name in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need create multiple files with different names but I recive data each seconds then I need save this data in each file with diferent names but my only code makes a file and when you receive another data this over write the existing file and not create another.

This is my code:

```
name= datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S.%f')[:-3]
   filename = "Json/%s.json"% name

def get_json():
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
                except OSError as exc: # Guard against race condition
                    if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                        raise 
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
                f.write("Hello")

def net_is_up():
    while(1):
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0:
            print "[%s] Network is up!" % time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            #read_json()
            get_json()

        else: 
            print "[%s] Network is down :(" % time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: This code doesn't do anything because it never calls `get_json`. Is there a loop somewhere? Or is this file executed repeatedly? (If so, where's the call to `get_json`?) In short, this code is okay, and if you call `get_json`, it should create exactly one file, named after the time when the code was run.

Comment: As a wild guess, you may want to move those first two lines inside of `get_json`. (This would fix code that looks like this but then has a loop that calls `get_json` repeatedly without recalculating `filename`.)

Comment: get_json is call in method net_is_up()

Comment: Your edit seems to confirm my guess, so I've added an answer.

Comment: Problem is with os.path.dirname(filename) as if this dirname does not exists then it will return empty string and I think there will always be the folder with blank name or some error will surely be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these lines inside the `get_json` function:

```
name = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S.%f')[:-3]
filename = "Json/%s.json"% name
```

As it stands now, `filename` is only calculated once, when you start this script. You need to do it each time you're going to save a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
def get_json():
    name= datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S.%f')[:-3]
    filename = "Json/%s.json"% name
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
                except OSError as exc: # Guard against race condition
                    if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                        raise 
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
                f.write("Hello")

def net_is_up():
    while(1):
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0:
            print "[%s] Network is up!" % time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            #read_json()
            get_json()

        else: 
            print "[%s] Network is down :(" % time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        time.sleep(60)
```